# How to Store Names of All European Langue in mySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

When I store names in Russian or in greek, or any other eastern european Langue my database store the special characters as some hexacode format.

For Example:
Pellonpää -> Pellonpu00e4u00e4

I get to name part of shipping address, and I store it as Long text in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`00e4` is a unicode "codepoint", not UTF-8.  Go back to the source of the text to find the problem.  MySQL never generates `\u00e4`.  (Also, there is a backslash that was lost in the display somehow.)

If you used PHP to construct JSON, then it was caused there.  Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in the second argument to `json_encode`.  See [*here*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) .